# Switching images based on arduino input in a python 2.7 generated Tkinter window won't show the images

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I wrote an Arduino code which reacts to buttons and physical interactions and then send the results to the computer on which my Python program (2.7) is running.

The Python code has two functions:

1. Create a new text file named after the unixtimestamp and fill it with all the data it receives.
2. Look through the data it receives for the code phrases `"a1"` and `"b1"` and then show the corresponding image.

When the Arduino starts it will send the `"a1"` as a first value to fill the window. After that, it should switch based on the data it sends.

This is my current code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *
import serial
import time

root = Tk()
prompt = StringVar()
root.title("vision")
label = Label(root, fg="dark green")
label.pack()
frame = Frame(root,background='red')
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(height=200,width=200)
canvas.pack()


timestamp = int(time.time())
filename=str(timestamp)+".txt"
f = open(str(filename),"w") 
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(filename))
f.write("\n")


arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', 115200, timeout=.1)
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()[:-2] #the last bit gets rid of the new-line chars
    print data
    f.write(str(data))
    f.write("\n")
    #Invoking through button
    TextWindow = Label(frame,anchor = NW, justify = LEFT, bg= 'white', fg   = 'blue', textvariable = prompt, width = 75, height=20)
    TextWindow.pack(side = TOP)

    if data == "a1": 
      canvas.delete("all")
      image1 = PhotoImage(file = "c2.gif")
      canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=image1)
      canvas.image = image1


    if data == "b1": 
      canvas.delete("all")
      image1 = PhotoImage(file = "c2.gif")
      canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=image1)
      canvas.image = image1
 
    root.mainloop()
```

It generates the window but it is empty.
I can not seem to find where my error is.

Additionally:
I used another tutorial which gave me the basic code for the GUI and images. In this there are two buttons which switch the images which works.

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *
pathy = randint(1, 2)
root = Tk()
prompt = StringVar()
root.title("vision")
label = Label(root, fg="dark green")
label.pack()
frame = Frame(root,background='red')
frame.pack()
canvas = Canvas(height=200,width=200)
canvas.pack()

def Image1():
    canvas.delete("all")
    image1 = PhotoImage(file = "c2.gif")
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=image1)
    canvas.image = image1

def Image2():
    canvas.delete("all")
    image1 = PhotoImage(file = "c1.gif")
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=image1)
    canvas.image = image1

TextWindow = Label(frame,anchor = NW, justify = LEFT, bg= 'white', fg   = 'blue', textvariable = prompt, width = 75, height=20)
TextWindow.pack(side = TOP)

conversationbutton = Button(frame, text='right button',width=25,fg="green",command = Image1)
conversationbutton.pack(side = RIGHT)

stopbutton = Button(frame, text='left button',width=25,fg="red",command = Image2)
stopbutton.pack(side = RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this indentation really how your code is? You have an infinite loop `root.mainloop()` inside an infinite loop `while True`. While I don't know if it's the only problem, but you should be calling `mainloop` exactly once in a tkinter program.

Comment: It was planned to be only one infinite loop with the "while true" but that did not work at all with the "mainloop" I was able to get at least the window.

Comment: Once `root.mainloop()` is called, you have to use callbacks to run code

Answer (score 0):

Once the `mainloop()` function has been called you have to use callbacks in order to run your own code. The Tkinter `after()` method can be used to run a section of code after a set amount of time.

In your case your code would look something like:

```
def update():
    #your code here
    root.after(1000, update)
update()
root.mainloop()
```

Calling `root.after()` inside of the update functions allows the function to keep running until the window is closed.

The after method as described at [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) gives the arguments as: 
`root.after(milliseconds, callback)`

In your case you might have to call your processing code more often then every second.